# multiple httpclient post using foreach not posting in order

Tags: angular, entity-framework, .net-core

So I have this problem where I want to post multiple http post using foreach loop. The problem is that the posted data is not in order, I mean the data is saved to the database but the data is not in order.

here is the sample data to be posted

```
    {
        "logsysid": 0,
        "CountMe": 1,
        "MachineNumber": 1,
        "EmpIDNo": "AAAAA",
        "IndRegID": "101",
        "InOut": 0,
        "verify": 0,
        "DateTimeRecord": "06/27/2022 6:48:47 AM",
        "machineLoc": null,
        "DateOnlyRecord": "/Date(1656259200000)/",
        "TimeOnlyRecord": "/Date(1656456527000)/",
        "errcode": 0,
        "errmessage": null
    },
    {
        "logsysid": 0,
        "CountMe": 2,
        "MachineNumber": 1,
        "EmpIDNo": "BBBBB",
        "IndRegID": "102",
        "InOut": 0,
        "verify": 0,
        "DateTimeRecord": "06/27/2022 6:48:52 AM",
        "machineLoc": null,
        "DateOnlyRecord": "/Date(1656259200000)/",
        "TimeOnlyRecord": "/Date(1656456532000)/",
        "errcode": 0,
        "errmessage": null
    },
    {
        "logsysid": 0,
        "CountMe": 3,
        "MachineNumber": 1,
        "EmpIDNo": "CCCCC",
        "IndRegID": "103",
        "InOut": 0,
        "verify": 0,
        "DateTimeRecord": "06/27/2022 6:49:06 AM",
        "machineLoc": null,
        "DateOnlyRecord": "/Date(1656259200000)/",
        "TimeOnlyRecord": "/Date(1656456546000)/",
        "errcode": 0,
        "errmessage": null
    }
```

here is my code

```
var ids = this.allData.map(data => data.CountMe).sort((a, b) => a - b);

ids.forEach((value, idx, arry) => {
  var parseDateTime = new Date(this.allData.find(x => x.CountMe === value).DateTimeRecord);
  var dateOnly = moment(parseDateTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  var timeOnly = moment(parseDateTime).format('HH:mm:ss').toString();
  var dateTime = moment(parseDateTime).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ');
  var empCode = this.allData.find(x => x.CountMe === value).EmpIDNo;
  var logType = this.allData.find(x => x.CountMe === value).InOut;

  const body = {
    empcode: empCode,
    logtype: logType,
    trndate: dateOnly,
    trntime: timeOnly,
    svrtime: dateTime
  }

  this.spinner.show();
  this.apiservice.insertLogs(body).subscribe((data: any) => {
    var result = data;
    if (result == 1) {
      if (idx === arry.length - 1) {
        $('#dtrTable').DataTable().clear().destroy();
        this.allData = [];
        this.toastr.success("Successfully uploaded logs to server", '', { timeOut: 10000 });
      }
    } else if (result == 0) {
      this.toastr.error("Error occured!")
    }
    this.spinner.hide();
  },
    (error: any) => {
      this.toastr.error(error.message);
      console.log(error.message);
      this.spinner.hide();
    })
});
```

As you can see I sorted the data by `CountMe`. EmpIDNo `AAAAA` should be the first to be saved in the database. But the data that is saved is ordered randomly, like EmpIDNo `BBBBB` is saved first. The table has a column name `ID` which is the `Primary Key` with auto increment. So EmpIDNo `AAAAA` should have the `ID` 1, `BBBBB` should have 2 etc. How to fix this?

This is my controller.cs

```
    [HttpPost("insertdtr")]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult<int> InsertDtr(Dtr model)
    {
        int result = 0;
        try
        {
            using (dbContext _dbcontext = new())
            {
                Dtr obj = new()
                {
                    Empcode = model.Empcode,
                    Logtype = model.Logtype,
                    Trndate = model.Trndate,
                    Trntime = model.Trntime,
                    SvrTime = model.SvrTime
                };

                _dbcontext.Dtrs.Add(obj);
                _dbcontext.SaveChanges();

                result = 1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            result = 0;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: the javascript `forEach` loop will not wait for each iteration to complete before kicking off the next. use a `for...of loop` instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: What do you mean `order`? Tables have no implicit order, even when they have a clustered key. Query results have none either, unless imposed by an `ORDER BY` clause. Without it, the server is free to use the cheapest way possible to return results.

Comment: Instead of posting records one by one, post an array of all the records at once as an array and accept a `Dtr[]` array on the other side. Add all of them to the context then call `SaveChanges` once. This will insert all records in a single internal transaction. Instead of N network and database requests, you'll have only a single request and a single DB operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you just need to do is create an array and post it directly and if your model is same than you also need not to create a new list and add objects iteratively. All your records will be stored in proper sequence and entity framework will do the job for you.

```
[HttpPost("insertdtr")]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult<int> InsertDtr(List<Dtr> list)
{
    int result = 0;
    try
    {
        using (dbContext _dbcontext = new())
        {

            _dbcontext.Dtrs.AddRange(list);
            _dbcontext.SaveChanges();

            result = 1;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        result = 0;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: this works but the data is still uploaded randomly. But thanks to this answer I got an idea, I loop each list and use `Add` rather than using `AddRange`